# Compare two columns and check if the values of other columns have increased or decreased

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with multiples columns. I have one column (sequence) of unique sequences that I want to compare with the next release of this data.frame and check how many peptides they have and check if this number has been increased or decreased.

I take this data.frame from a data base, but the problem is that this data base generates new random sequence positions in each release(See 2º release).

```
1ºRelease
    ID  | sequence | ... | Peptides | nºproject
    1 | atggggg  | ... | 65       | project 
    2 | tgatgat  | ... | 3        | project 
    3 | actgat   | ... | 32       | project 
    4 | atgtagtt | ... | 25       | project 
    5 | ttttaaat | ... | 32       | project 



2ºrelease
    ID  | sequence | ... | Peptides | nºproject
    1 | atggggg  | ... | 66       | project 
    2 | tgatgat  | ... | 5        | project 
    3 | actgat   | ... | 36       | project 
    4 | ATTTGGGG | ... | 26       | project *** New one ***
    5 | ATTGATGA | ... | 32       | project *** New one ***
    6 | atgtagtt | ... | 47       | project 
    7 | ttttaaat | ... | 38       | project
```

I would not have any problem to use duplicate function if in each release the new sequences were put at the end of the column, but unfortunately this is done randomly.

Here you have an example:

1º release:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), 
.Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4" ,"5") ), 
sequence = structure(c(1L,2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), 
.Label = c(" actgat   "," atagattg ", " atatagag ", " atggggg  ", " atgtagtt "), class = "factor"), 
peptides = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), 
.Label = c(" 54  ", " 84  ",  " 32  ", " 36  ", "12"),
class = "factor"), n_project = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
.Label = " project ", class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "sequence", "peptides", "n_project"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -5L))
```

2º release:

```
df2 <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), 
.Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4" ,"5" ,"6", "7" ) ), 
sequence = structure(c(1L,2L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L), 
.Label = c(" actgat   "," atagattg ", " atatagag ", " atggggg  ", " atgtagtt ", " gggatgac ", " TATATCC ", " TTTTAAAT "), class = "factor"), 
peptides = structure(c(1L, 2L,7L,8L, 3L, 4L, 5L), 
.Label = c(" 56  ", " 85  ",  " 31  ", " 36  ", "15", "10", "76", "98", "34", "76"),
class = "factor"), n_project = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
.Label = " project ", class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "sequence", "peptides", "n_project"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -7L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a key in common, you can use a `join`.

In `tidyverse` that would look like this:

library(tidyverse)

```
df %>% 
  full_join(df2, by = "sequence", suffix = c(".1", ".2")) %>%
  # Fix data to convert to character and numeric
  mutate_each(funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))), starts_with("pept")) %>%
  # See difference
  mutate(change = peptides.2 - peptides.1)

#> Warning in full_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y): joining
#> factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
#>   ID.1   sequence peptides.1 n_project.1 ID.2 peptides.2 n_project.2  change
#> 1    1  actgat            54    project     1         56    project       2
#> 2    2  atagattg          84    project     2         85    project       1
#> 3    3  atatagag          32    project     5         31    project      -1
#> 4    4  atggggg           36    project     6         36    project       0
#> 5    5  atgtagtt          12    project     7         15    project       3
#> 6   NA   TATATCC          NA        <NA>    3         76    project      NA
#> 7   NA  TTTTAAAT          NA        <NA>    4         98    project      NA
```

With `full_join` we see:

1. What matches between `df` and `df2`.
2. The new rows in `df2` (which have `NA` values for the peptides)
3. The change in peptides over time.

In this case I've assumed that your `sequence` data is case sensitive.

### Base R

You can also do this in base R with `merge`, but I prefer the `tidyverse` syntax above.

```
merge(df, df2, by = "sequence", all = T)
#>     sequence ID.x peptides.x n_project.x ID.y peptides.y n_project.y
#> 1  actgat       1       54      project     1       56      project 
#> 2  atagattg     2       84      project     2       85      project 
#> 3  atatagag     3       32      project     5       31      project 
#> 4  atggggg      4       36      project     6       36      project 
#> 5  atgtagtt     5         12    project     7         15    project 
#> 6   TATATCC    NA       <NA>        <NA>    3         76    project 
#> 7  TTTTAAAT    NA       <NA>        <NA>    4         98    project
```

Comment: And how can I count the peptides later?

Comment: The total number of peptides? The ones that are new? The ones that are old? What do you mean?

Comment: As I said in the introduction, I want to join these dates because I want to compare one old release with new release and check how many peptides I have and if the number of peptides has been increased or decreased.

Comment: Is that not the `change` column? (`0` would be no change). If you want something else, I'm unclear.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the change column. Thank so much, that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

First convert your peptide counts to numeric (they're a factor with numeric character labels, that's a bit messed up):

```
> df$peptides=as.numeric(as.character(df$peptides))
> df2$peptides=as.numeric(as.character(df2$peptides))
```

A left join will match the new data onto the old ones:

```
> require(dplyr)
> left_join(df, df2, c("sequence"="sequence"))
  ID.x   sequence peptides.x n_project.x ID.y peptides.y n_project.y
1    1  actgat            54    project     1         56    project 
2    2  atagattg          84    project     2         85    project 
3    3  atatagag          32    project     5         31    project 
4    4  atggggg           36    project     6         36    project 
5    5  atgtagtt          12    project     7         15    project 
Warning message:
In left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y) :
  joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
```

Ignore the warning. A left join and a filter will find the ones where the peptide number has increased:

```
> filter(left_join(df, df2, c("sequence"="sequence")), peptides.y>peptides.x)
  ID.x   sequence peptides.x n_project.x ID.y peptides.y n_project.y
1    1  actgat            54    project     1         56    project 
2    2  atagattg          84    project     2         85    project 
3    5  atgtagtt          12    project     7         15    project
```

Save that as a new data frame, or whatever.

As a check, the ones that have decreased or unchanged:

```
> filter(left_join(df, df2, c("sequence"="sequence")), peptides.y<=peptides.x)
  ID.x   sequence peptides.x n_project.x ID.y peptides.y n_project.y
1    3  atatagag          32    project     5         31    project 
2    4  atggggg           36    project     6         36    project
```

Comment: Is it possible to use another condition to join the data. I mean for example using sequence = sequence AND modification=modification. (Modification would be another column). I have seen that some sequences are repeated but with different modifications, so when I use your method, the join is not correct

Comment: Ok, I got it. `left_join(df, df2, by = c("sequence","modifications"))`. But now my problem is that left_join completes the column with NA, so filter function can't count ones were the peptide number has increased.

Answer (score 4):

@Spacedman's solution but with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
setDT(df, key = 'sequence')
setDT(df2, key = 'sequence')
df2[df]
```

Or as one-liner (possible with the newest version of data.table) :

```
library("data.table")
setDT(df2)[df, on="sequence"]
```

Comment: That does the join, but for completeness you should probably show how to get the rows where the peptide number has increased.